# Compute probabilities after coxph

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate some probabilities after running survival analysis using `coxph` from the `survival` package. I've read a bunch of posts but I can't seem to find one that answers this particular question.

I have a model like

```
coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ x1 + x2)
```

And I'm interested in computing the probability that an individual who has lived until time `t` will die before time `t+1`.

Is this possible? I think I just need to find the estimate of the hazard function at time t, but I'm wondering how to compute this. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: this sounds more like statistics help than coding help. can you clarify which you need?

Comment: Fair point @rawr. I will double check on my statistics, but assuming I do want to compute estimates for the hazard function h(t) (not the integrated/cumulative hazard function) is there a way to do that? Can I do something like use `predict.coxph` with arg `type = 'risk'` to compute exp(X*beta) and then multiply this by the baseline hazards from `basehaz`? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes this can be done by the following code:

```
cox.fit<- coxph(Surv(df$time,df$Status)~X1+X2+X3+X4))
summary(cox.fit)
predicted_cox.fit<-survfit(cox.fit)
Exp_Beta<- predict(predicted_cox.fit,type='lp')
basehaz_cox<-basehaz(cox.fit)

Predicted_probability_at_t1 <- as.data.frame((exp(-basehaz_cox(t1))^(exp(Exp_Beta))
```